# How to set image icon to Jtree node on right side of label depends on Node value?

Tags: java, swing

I have searched a lot but solutions that i got are not as per my need.I am showing multiple servers in tree structure.I want to set icon on right side of server(localhost) node when its value gets change.Please provide me a way to set icon.In following image localhost is server name. Its server node.

[image]

```
 public class ServerInfo{
    private Boolean isShotDetected =false;

    public Boolean getIsShotDetected() {
        return isShotDetected;
    }
    public void setIsShotDetected(Boolean isShotDetected) {
        this.isShotDetected = isShotDetected;
    }
  }


   class MyTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    private Border border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2);

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded,
            boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {

        JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected, expanded, leaf, row,
                hasFocus);
          DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;

        if (expanded) {
            setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 13));

        } else {
            setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        }

        if (node instanceof ServerNode) {
            ServerInfo info = ((ServerNode) node).getMultiSite();
            if (info.getIsShotDetected()) {
                // label.setAlignmentX(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                label.setIcon(redBall);
            }

        }
        label.setBorder(border);

        return label;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this: `label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEADING);`

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TRAILING);
if (node instanceof ServerNode) {
    ServerInfo info = ((ServerNode) node).getMultiSite();
    if (info.getIsShotDetected()) {
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEADING);
        label.setIcon(redBall);
    }

}
```